# Vue JS nested component doesnt show up in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I made two VueJS components, one that shows a modal and one that shows a couple of HTML inputs.

Both components work fine when used separately, but when I nest them, the inner component does not end up inside the DOM. What am I doing wrong?

My main html looks like this:

```
    <modal-dialog v-show="Modal"
                  title="Add transducer">
        <add-transducer></add-transducer>
    </modal-dialog>
```

My two components look like this:

```
    Vue.component('modal-dialog', {
    props: ['title'],
    template:  `<div class="background-modal" >
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="graph-wrapper" id="AddTransducer">
                    <h3>{{ title }}</h3> <i class="fa fa-times-circle float-right color-red"></i>
                    <div class="max-height-75vh">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div >`,
    methods: {

    }
});
```

and

```
    Vue.component('add-transducer', {
    props: [''],
    template: `<form id="addTransducer" v-on:submit="formValidation($event)">

                                <!------  Location  ------>
                                <label class="margin-top-20 " for="cbLocation">Location*</label>
                                <select id="cboLocation" name="cbLocation" v-if="showSelectLocation === true" v-model="cbLocation">
                                    <option selected disabled> -- select a Location -- </option>
                                    <option v-for="loc in lstLocations" :value="loc.RecID">{{loc.Name}}</option>
                                </select>

                                <!--  Add button  -->
                                <a v-if="btnAddLocation === true" v-on:click="freeInput('location')" class="add-button blue-gradient float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

                                <!--  Delete Button  -->
                                <a v-on:click="deleteInput('location')" v-if="btnDeleteLocation === true" class="add-button red-background float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

                                <!-- Text input field to add new Location -->
                                <input id="tbFreeInputLocation" name="tbFreeInputLocation" v-if="tbFreeInputLocation === true" v-model="inputLocation" type="text" class="free-input" :placeholder="tbFreeInputPlaceholder" />

                                <p v-if="errors.length" class="color-red "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {{errors[0]}}</p>

                                <!------ Manufacturer ------>
                                <label for="cbManufacturer" class="margin-top-20">Manufacturer*</label>
                                <select name="cbManufacturer" v-if="showSelectManufacturer === true" v-model="cbManufacturer">
                                    <option selected disabled> -- select a Manufacturer -- </option>
                                    <option v-for="manuf in lstManufacturers" :value="manuf.RecID">{{manuf.Name}}</option>
                                </select>

                                <!--  Add button  -->
                                <a v-if="btnAddManufacturer === true" v-on:click="freeInput('manufacturer')" class="add-button blue-gradient float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

                                <!--  Delete Button  -->
                                <a v-on:click="deleteInput('manufacturer')" v-if="btnDeleteManufacturer === true" class="add-button red-background float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

                                <!-- Text input field to add new Manufacturer -->
                                <input id="tbFreeInputManufacturer" name="tbFreeInputManufacturer" v-if="tbFreeInputManufacturer === true" v-model="inputManufacturer" type="text" class="free-input" :placeholder="tbFreeInputPlaceholder" />

                                <p v-if="errors.length" class="color-red "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {{errors[1]}}</p>

                                <!------  Model ------>

                                <label for="cbModel" class="margin-top-20">Model*</label>
                                <select name="cbModel" v-if="showSelectModel === true" v-model="cbModel">
                                    <option selected disabled> -- select a Model -- </option>
                                    <option v-for="model in lstModels" :value="model.RecID">{{model.Model}}</option>
                                </select>

                                <!--  Add button  -->
                                <a v-if="btnAddModel === true" v-on:click="freeInput('model')" class="add-button blue-gradient float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

                                <!--  Delete Button  -->
                                <a v-on:click="deleteInput('model')" v-if="btnDeleteModel === true" class="add-button red-background float-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

                                <!-- Text input field to add new Manufacturer -->
                                <input id="tbFreeInputModel" name="tbFreeInputModel" v-if="tbFreeInputModel === true" v-model="inputModel" type="text" class="free-input" :placeholder="tbFreeInputPlaceholder" />

                                <p v-if="errors.length" class="color-red "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {{errors[2]}}</p>

                                <!--  Serial Number -->
                                <label for="tbSerial" class="margin-top-20">Serial Number*</label>
                                <input type="text" name="tbSerial" v-model="tbSerial" />

                                <p v-if="errors.length" class="color-red "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {{errors[3]}}</p>

                                <!--  Inventory Number -->
                                <label for="tbInventory" class="margin-top-20">Inventory Number</label>
                                <input type="text" name="tbInventory" v-model="tbInventory" />

                                <!--  Date installed -->
                                <label for="tbDate" class="margin-top-20">Date installed</label>
                                <input type="date" name="tbDate" v-model="tbDate" />

                                <!--  Description -->
                                <label for="tbDescription" class="margin-top-20">Description</label>

                                <textarea name="tbDescription" v-model="tbDescription"></textarea>

                                <button type="submit" class="blue-gradient float-right  margin-bottom-40"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
                            </form>`,
    methods: {

    },
    mounted: function () {

        var self = this;

            $.get("/IQMonitor/GetAddTransducerModel",
                {
                    //Room for parameters
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    //Successfully added
                    //Add row to table
                    if (status === "success") {
                        //Add locations to selectionbox

                        self.lstLocations = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.Locations.length; i++) {
                            self.lstLocations.push(data.Locations[i]);
                        }

                        ////Add manufacturers to selectionbox
                        //vueApp.lstManufacturers = [];

                        //for (var i = 0; i < data.Manufacturers.length; i++) {
                        //  coAddTransducer.lstManufacturers.push(data.Manufacturers[i]);
                        //}

                    }

                });

    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            showSelectLocation: true,
            showSelectManufacturer: true,
            showSelectModel: true,
            tbFreeInputLocation: false,
            tbFreeInputManufacturer: false,
            tbFreeInputModel: false,
            inputLocation: '',
            inputManufacturer: '',
            inputModel: '',
            tbFreeInputPlaceholder: '',
            btnDeleteLocation: false,
            btnDeleteManufacturer: false,
            btnDeleteModel: false,
            btnAddLocation: true,
            btnAddManufacturer: true,
            btnAddModel: true,
            errors: [],
            cbLocation: null,
            cbManufacturer: null,
            cbModel: null,
            tbSerial: null,
            tbInventory: null,
            tbDate: null,
            tbDescription: null,

            lstLocations: [],
            lstManufacturers: [],
            lstModels: []
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html), they are a mechanism for Vue components that allows you to compose your components in a way other than the strict parent-child relationship. Slots give you an outlet to place content in new places or make components more generic.

```
<div class="max-height-75vh">
   <slot></slot>
</div>
```

```
<modal-dialog v-show="Modal" title="Add transducer">
   <add-transducer></add-transducer>
</modal-dialog>
```